# Indexed Family of Sets and infinite/finite subset

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My problem reads:

Consider the indexed family of sets $A_n= (\frac{-n}{n+1}, \frac{n}{n+1})$ for $n\in\mathbb{N} $.

a) Show that { A$_n$ : n$\in\mathbb{N}$} covers $(-1,1)$

b) Show that if I is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then { A$_n$ : n$\in I$} does not cover $(-1,1).$

**My work:**

I am thinking I need to pick an n such that my x is also within that interval. However, I am having issues with this part of my argument. I was thinking along the lines of forming an inequality, but I am not too sure how to phrase/set this up. Would something like $\frac{-n}{n+1} < x < \frac{n}{n+1}$ or would I need to split this into two cases.

For part b, intuitively it makes sense to me that it would not cover $(-1,1)$ because we can always find an $x$ that is not in the set, and thus a larger $n$ that would include such an $x.$ However, I am not too sure how to phrase this reasoning correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you thought was right, and what you need is some points:

For the part a, you may want to use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1.$

For the other part, since $I$ is a $\textbf{finite}$ subset of $\mathbb{N},$ then you and find any of its upper bound and use it to find a counterexample.

Edit: A formal proof may be written like:

a) For any $x\in [0,1),$ since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1,$ there exists some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{m}{m+1}>x,$ and hence $x\in A_m.$ The case $x\in (-1,0]$ is similar.

Comment: Yeah, more precisely, since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{-n}{n+1}=-1,$ then given any $x\in (-1,0),$ there exists some $n_{0}$ such that $\frac{-n_{0}}{n_{0}+1}<x.$

Comment: Hmm, okay. I think I am more just having an issue writing this out concisely. Should I start with my x in (-1,0) and then proceed to state the limit and then my conclusion? Or should I state the inequality before mentioning the limit? I appreciate the help as I have not been exposed to these kinds of proofs yet!

Comment: Okay, I edit my post to state it formally.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will then update what I have thought up for the case of when x is in (0,1) and also part b.

Comment: Then I write down a) first.

Comment: Okay, I just want to clarify why is it that the fact of the limit gives us that $\frac{-n}{n+1}$ < x ? I note the limit and I think I do get it, but I think I just need a bit more clarity.

Comment: This is based on the definition of limit. That $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$ means for any $\epsilon>0,$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\ge N,$ we have $|\frac{n}{n+1}-1|<\epsilon.$ Here giving $x$ is playing the role of giving such an $\epsilon.$

Comment: Yeah, I think, indeed, given some $x,$ you can directly calculate the required $n,$ at least for this problem ww

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Try solving the inequality $\frac{-n}{n+1}<x< \frac{n}{n+1}$ directly xD

Comment: Oh you mean this way direct also works?

Comment: For this problem, it seems feasible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65397/discussion-between-sam-and-tommy-xu3).